# Appropriate Answer [Before Edit]

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225891/774078

This answer. Please notice the edit! I was about to downvote this answer because it did not actually solve it, it just explained why it didn't work. (Kind of like a 50% answer).

Notice the comment, he said he was editting. Ok, cool, I didn't downvote and his answer is good.

This brought on the question (or series of questions): When writing an answer, and you post something (I guess as a "placeholder"), I would assume I could downvote until the answer is editted, but what is the "breaking point" for a placeholder?

One time I saw an answer "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" that was editted to the right answer.

Even when it became a right answer it wasn't upvoted.

Comment: Related: [Fastest gun in the west problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731)

Comment: Pardon the duplicate, should I delete or let it close?

Comment: Just leave it be.

Comment: No shame in an occasional duplicate, especially on Meta where wording and presentation of an issue can vary drastically.